# Google speech API . Speech to text recognition with Mathematica

Tags: webservices, sound

Has anyone tried to use the Google speech API with Mathematica? This would open up exciting possibilities when combined with the free form input already available in Mathematica and with the recently announced "Wolfram Language everywhere" strategy.

Comment: Wonderful! Imagine all those four letter words I use while debugging, automagically turned into code!

Comment: I think this will be very interesting. I can see one giving speech commands to Mathematica which will in turn send the command to W/Alpha over the internet and getting the response back and seeing a plot drawn on the screen all of which is done without moving a mouse or touching a keyboard. This might open the door to many who like to try programming but may be not able to use the mouse or the keyboard for some reason.

Comment: I've used the Dictation feature (Mac OS X) to input plain text. But try saying "plot the sine of x" to Mathematica and you'll get "plot the sign of eggs", "cosine" looks for "coastline", and "pi" looks for "pie". You end up spending more time correcting it than getting anything done.

Comment: @Nasser exactly! there are fantastic accessibility implications. I think/hope using this web service is as simple as sending a mp3 file to a URL, so I look forward to seeing some good answers

Comment: @cormullion I am not so much interested in giving mathematica commands verbally, but rather to give commands to a generic app programmed in the WL (Wolfram Language). Besides the API might be hopefully programmed to search in a restricted vocabulary for specialized words